# Not understanding Arel usage ( Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have been looking into Arel ( mostly because of its usage in ransack gem for advanced search ) .I have seen some guides but I do not quite understand how it works.

Having for example

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)
users.where(users[:name].eq('amy'))
# => SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.name = 'amy'
```

This will produce a SQL query, but not execute it.
How can I use the result ? How should an Arel be written&where ( model, view, controller?)

I know it may seem a bit broad, but what I'm trying to see is where/how to use arel to search in my tables.

Comment: *"This will produce a SQL query, but not execute it"* if you were to capture the result of that in a variable e.g. `users_named_amy = users.where(users[:name].eq('amy'))` then you can act on the resulting `User` objects the same way you would any other AR Query?

Answer (score 4):

One use of Arel is to build conditions for your models. It's also useful to know that Rails itself is using Arel under the hood whenever you make a query like this:

```
User.where(name: 'amy')
```

The Arel will be something equivalent to:

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:name].eq('amy'))
```

Obviously, for this example writing Arel directly isn't needed, but Arel allows more complex queries to be composed in code where you'd normally need to drop down to handwriting SQL clauses (such as using other operators like `IN`, `>`, `<` etc.)

For instance, to find your users over who are over 18:

```
User.where('age >= ?', 18)
```

can be written as

```
User.where(User.arel_table[:age].gteq(18))
```

You can also use Arel to build a fully formed SQL query and then pass this to Active Record to execute it:

```
table = User.arel_table
sql = table.project(:id).where(table[:name].eq('amy')).to_sql # => "SELECT id FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"name\" = 'amy'"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

The result will be an array of hashes where the keys are the field names selected in the query.